# hashing and checking password in java

Tags: java, hash

Hi I write a simple database program where I need to have users. I write a simple program to test my idea and it seems to work, but I wonder if my idea is correct.

I hash passwords with salt:

```
Random random = new Random();
byte[] salt = new byte[16];
random.nextBytes(salt);
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec("pass123".toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 128);
SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
byte[] hash = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
```

store them as a string hash + salt in database:

```
String index  = enc.encodeToString(salt) + "$"+ enc.encodeToString(hash);
```

and when user is logging get my string from database and check if pass is correct:

```
String stored[] = index.split("\\$");
KeySpec spec1 = new PBEKeySpec("haslo1234fdfgds".toCharArray(), stored[0].getBytes(), 65536, 128);
SecretKeyFactory f1 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
byte[] hash1 = f.generateSecret(spec1).getEncoded();
if(stored[1].equals(enc.encodeToString(hash1))) return true;
```

I know that in Base64 is decoder, but I wonder if I have to use it when this solution seems to work?
I am new in this so there is a huge possibility I forget about something, that's why I want to ask if my idea is ok.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If the password is not the same, passwords won't match. If the salt is not the same, passwords won't match either. You should at least test that you can successfully verify passwords with your algorithm. If you can't, there is a problem, isn't there?

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work, but I worry that i forget about something, so I want someone smarter look on it, it simply seems to be too easy.

Comment: *it seems to work*: no, it doesn't. Post the actual test you tried, because the code you posted can't possibly work: you're not using the same salt when generating the hash and when checking it.

Comment: why not the same? I save the salt with hash in one string and store it in database. When I get this string from database I split them and pass stored[0](saved salt) to PBEKeySpec constructor. The tests are similar to code above just save and get pass from database. And in example above I got false, but when i change the second password into the same as first I got true. Or when I cast salt to byte it not give me a original salt and i need to somehow decode it?

Comment: ok, I know what you mean,when I compare a string representing salt there are the same store[0] equals salt encoded to string, but when i compare salt and store[0] it was different. So I need to store in some place a salt or I can get a salt from this string, by decoding it? I got a right test by a mistake.

Comment: When encoding you use a random, 16-bytes-long byte array. When decoding, you use the bytes of the string obtained from the base-64 encoding of that byte array. You must base64-decode that string first, to obtain the same 16-bytes-long byte array. See https://gist.github.com/jnizet/edeaaae1f583b5c6ecf1 for the corrected code, and a correct test.